# Count how many equal strings are in XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I'm wondering if there is a method to check how many equal strings are in an XML file. For example this is the XML file:

```
<Root>
  <task>
    <sub1>test</sub1>
    <sub2>hello</sub2>
    <sub3>csharp</sub3>
  </task>
  <task>
    <sub1>test2</sub1>
    <sub2>hello2</sub2>
    <sub3>csharp2</sub3>
  </task>
  <task>
    <sub1>test3</sub1>
    <sub2>hello3</sub2>
    <sub3>csharp3</sub3>
  </task>
  <task>
    <sub1>test</sub1>
    <sub2>hello4</sub2>
    <sub3>csharp4</sub3>
  </task>
</Root>
```

As you can see `node.Innertext = "test"` exists twice. I'm wondering how I can count that? I tried something like

`client["sub1"].InnerText.Count`

but this counts the number of character in this string.

Suggestions appreciated :)

**EDIT:** I parse the XML file using `XmlDocument`

Comment: How are you currently parsing the xml?

Comment: Are you using the `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` class to parse the XML?

Comment: Sorry forgot, I'll edit the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Select elements you want to check (e.g. all sub elements of all tasks) and group them by value:

```
xdoc.Root.Elements("task").SelectMany(t => t.Elements())
    .GroupBy(e => e.Value)
    .Select(g => new { Text = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
```

Query syntax:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var result = from t in xdoc.Root.Elements("task")
             from e in t.Elements()
             group e by e.Value into g
             select new {
                  Text = g.Key,
                  Count = g.Count()
             };
```

With XPath:

```
var result = from e in xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//task/*")
             group e by e.Value into g
             select new {
                 Text = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Count()
             };
```

For your sample xml result will be:

```
[
  { Text: "test", Count: 2 },
  { Text: "hello", Count: 1 },
  { Text: "csharp", Count: 1 },
  { Text: "test2", Count: 1 },
  { Text: "hello2", Count: 1 },
  { Text: "csharp2", Count: 1 },
  { Text: "test3", Count: 1 },
  { Text: "hello3", Count: 1 },
  { Text: "csharp3", Count: 1 },
  { Text: "hello4", Count: 1 },
  { Text: "csharp4", Count: 1 }
]
```

You can filter results by count if you want to get only text which exist more than once:

```
 result.Where(x => x.Count > 1)
```

---

Same query for `XmlDocument`:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path_to_xml);
var result = from XmlNode n in doc.SelectNodes("//task/*")
             group n by n.InnerText into g
             select new {
                 Text = g.Key,
                 Count = g.Count()
             };
```

Comment: I think this is for parsing the xml with `XDocument`? Because I'm using `XmlDocument` to parse it and got no `.Root` property for my `XmlDocument`

Comment: Times like these, I bloody love LINQ :)

Comment: @Roman yep, thats for XDocument and Linq to Xml. I suggest you to use Linq for parsing xml

Comment: @Roman Why not use XDocument instead? It makes things much easier.

Comment: @MatthewWatson What exactly is easier this way? :)

Comment: @Roman I added also sample for XmlDocument :) But LINQ to XML in general case would be much simpler

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Ah nice, thank you. I will try it with Linq in another test WinFormApp. But I don't really understand the code. I never saw anything like this, is that something special or why is it possible to write that without any semicolons etc? And if I now want a `MsgBox` to display how many of the element `InnerText` `sub1` exists, how can I do that? `MessageBox.Show(xxx);`?

Comment: @Roman `MessageBox.Show(xdoc.Descendants("sub1").Count().ToString())` I suggest you to read [Querying XML Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387050.aspx)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy but this is also just for `XDocument`? It's working in `XDocument` I tested it but I want to know how to do that using `XmlDocument` as well :)

Comment: @Roman with XmlDocument you can use XPath `doc.SelectNodes("//task/sub1").Count`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Sounds logical, but then it counts how many nodes `called "sub1"` exists, not how many called `"sub1" with the same InnerText` exists

Comment: @Roman you didn't ask for same inner text: `display how many of the element InnerText sub1 exists` anyway - that's a different question and it should be asked separately

Comment: Okay, but you solved the first step I need :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
var dubs = XDocument.Parse(xml)
            .Descendants("task")
            .GroupBy(g => (string)g.Attribute("sub1"))
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .Select(g => g.Key);
```